# Why is 'plt.imshow' showing the original image when the actual values are changed?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, image-processing

### What is the problem of this piece of code?

It modifies the values but when it wants to show me the actual modified image, it will show me the original image again.
Am I doing something wrong?

And let me explain this in images too:

1- Original image:

[image]

2- Modified image:

[image]

As it is obvious from histogram of images, the values are changed but the pictures are showing me exactly the same image.

This is the code for this pages to come up.

```py
# Load the image
img = cv2.imread(current_dir + "/img.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

plt.figure("Original Image", figsize=(6, 6))
plt.subplot(211)
plt.title("Original Image")
plt.imshow(img, "gray")
plt.subplot(212)
hist_full = cv2.calcHist([img], [0], None, [256], [0, 256])
plt.plot(hist_full)

img_min = np.amin(img)
img_max = np.amax(img)
gray_levels = np.arange(256, dtype=np.uint8)
gray_levels[:] = np.uint8(
    ((gray_levels - img_min) / (img_max - img_min)) * (30 - 0) + 0
)
img_shrunk = cv2.LUT(img, gray_levels)

plt.figure("Shrunk Original Image", figsize=(6, 6))
plt.subplot(211)
plt.title("Shrunk Original Image")
plt.imshow(img_shrunk, "gray")
plt.subplot(212)
hist_full = cv2.calcHist([img_shrunk], [0], None, [256], [0, 256])
plt.plot(hist_full)
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [grayscale image different in cv2.imshow() and matplotlib.pyplot.show()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69140016/grayscale-image-different-in-cv2-imshow-and-matplotlib-pyplot-show)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `imshow` automatically sets the visualization range. It does not assume or expect the input to be in [0-255]

Try

```
plt.imshow(img_shrunk, "gray", vmin=0,vmax=255)
```